# Two different colorscheme for vim based on GUI and Terminal version of Macvim

Tags: vim, vi, macvim

I use gui version of macvim for my general development activites. 
I use `mvim` from terminal also as I've mapped `mvim` to `vim` alias.

How can I open different color scheme in mvim based on whether they are opened in gui version or terminal version?

I want to set `solarized` colorscheme for gui version of macvim and
`grb256`(or anyother) colorscheme in terminal version of mvim.

How can we do this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if has("gui_running")
    colorscheme solarized
else
    colorscheme grb256
endif
```

And you can set any other things in there you prefer. This is the full block from my .vimrc:

```
if has('gui_running')
    let g:solarized_contrast = 'high'
    set guifont=Mensch:h14
    set antialias
    set background=light
    colorscheme solarized
else
    set background=dark
    colorscheme cobalt2
endif
```